# Vectorize for loops in MATLAB for faster execution

Tags: matlab, performance, loops, vectorization

I'm simulating the dynamic response of a linear system with uncertainty in one of the parameters of the stiffness matrix. In the code it is the `ds(17)` parameter of the data set array, which is substituted in the `KK` stiffness matrix of the dynamic system. All other parameters are constant.

First I calculate a random Gaussian normal distribution of the parameter and plot the result just to see the probability of the value falling into a certain interval. Even if I calculate 1e6 random samples it doesn't take much to compute.

Then I move into calculating the natural frequencies with the mean value of `k__p` stiffness (as denoted in the `KK` matrix) or `ds(17)` for my base system as a reference.

After defining my number of needed random samples `num = 1e3;` and designate mean value of `Km = 1e8;`, I move into the first for loop that substitutes the new random `ds(17)` value into the dynamic matrix `KK` (which is 18 degrees of freedom) and gives me the new natural frequencies, which I then plot into the next for loop.

With a `num = 1e2` my computer takes 30 seconds to give me the results, but 100 samples is way too few for what I need and for representing a Gaussian distribution, I would like to try with at least a thousand but my cpu can't handle, it's currently been running for more than 20 hours for 1e3 but I think I'm gonna stop it.

I have two questions regarding general programming practices: 
1. What is the correct way to preallocate acell array of matrices (Kcell and Fcell).
2. Is there a better way of creating an array or list or variables for a data set to input it into a function than what I did (the ds array)?

I tried to leave my code to the minimum for this example. I would appreciate any comments on how to make my code faster, thanks.

```
% clc;
% clear;
% close all;

%% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Simulation Data Array ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
ds(1) = degtorad(24.6);  

ds(2)  = 0.40;     
ds(3)  = 0.39;    
ds(4)  = 0.0774/2; 

ds(5)  = 2.35;     
ds(6)  = 3.00;     
ds(7)  = 0.2750/2; 

ds(8) = 5.43;     
ds(9) = 6.29;     
ds(10) = (0.1762/2)/cos(ds(1)); 

ds(11) = 0.66;     
ds(12) = 0.61;    
ds(13) = 0.1003/2; 

ds(14) = 1e8;      
ds(15) = 1e8;      
ds(16) = 1e8;      
ds(17) = 1e8;      

ds(18) = 0;        
ds(19) = 1e9;     
ds(20) = 0;        
ds(21) = 5e8;      

ds(22) = (2*pi/60)*[0]; 

%% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Calculate Matrices ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
[q_std,Kcell_std,MM_std,radius_std] = gear_eigen (1,ds); 

%% Simulate Model Properties
disp('Standard Eigenproblem Solution w^2*M*phi=K*phi');

% Natural Frequencies(Eigenvalues) & Mode Shapes(Eigenvectors)
[frqs_std] = eigenprob_KM (q_std,cell2mat(Kcell_std),MM_std,ds(22));

%% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ K Uncertainty ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
num   = 1e2;
Kl=6e7; Ku=14e7;   % lower and upper limits   
Km    = 1e8;       % Planet bearing stiffness (mean value)
width = 1e5;       % Interval width between values
STDEV = 10;        

epsilon = normrnd(0,STDEV,num,1)/100;                                                                
K_eps = Km*(1+epsilon);           
% K_eps = Kl+(Ku-Kl)*rand(num,1); % Method 2: uniform distribution

minK    = min(K_eps);
maxK    = max(K_eps);
dx      = width;                       % Interval width for empirical PDF
centers = minK : dx : maxK;            % Centre of Interval
edges   = minK-dx/2 : dx : maxK+dx/2;  % Edges of Interval
N       = histcounts(K_eps,edges);     % Count ocurrences of K
figure ('Name','Random Distribution')
subplot(1,2,1)
histogram(K_eps,centers)               % Plot random values vs occurrency 
axis([minK-dx maxK+dx 0 1.075*max(N)])
xlabel('Stiffness Value, \itK','FontSize',11)
ylabel('Frequency of Occurrence, \itn_{\rmi}','FontSize',11)


N   = N(1:end); % Frequency of Occurrence n
Ni  = [0 N 0]; 
Pri = Ni/(num*dx); %Rescale ordinate values to Pri
xi  = minK-dx : dx : maxK+dx;
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(xi,Pri,'.r',xi,Pri,'b')
hold on
axis([minK-dx maxK+dx 0 1.075*max(Pri)])
xlabel('Stiffness Value, \itK','FontSize',11)
ylabel('Approximation of  \itf_{\rmK}\rm(\itu\rm)','FontSize',11)
text(0.33,9.2,'MonteCarlo Simulation of Stiffness Uncertainty','FontSize' ,11)
legend('\itf_{\rmi}','Empirical pdf','location','eastoutside')
hold off
% edgeStart = 200;
% edgeEnd   = 600;
% eds = edges(edgeStart:edgeEnd);
% % Empirical prob that K will fall between edgeStart and edgeEnd
% Pr  = sum(Pri(edgeStart:edgeEnd))*dx;
% T_prob = table(edges(edgeStart),edges(edgeEnd),Pr);
% T_prob.Properties.VariableNames = {'IntervalStart' 'IntervalEnd' ... 
%                                    'Probability'}

% Calculate Natural Frequencies
Fcell{length(K_eps)} = []; % Preallocate memory for cell array
Kcell{length(K_eps)} = []; % Preallocate memory for cell array;

syms x__s     y__s    u__s ... 
     x__r     y__r    u__r ... 
     x__c     y__c    u__c ... 
     zeta__1  eta__1  u__1 ... 
     zeta__2  eta__2  u__2 ... 
     zeta__3  eta__3  u__3     

q = [x__s y__s u__s ...
     x__r y__r u__r ...
     x__c y__c u__c ...
     zeta__1 eta__1 u__1 ...
     zeta__2 eta__2 u__2 ...
     zeta__3 eta__3 u__3 ];

alpha = ds(1);
m__s  = ds(2);
m__ws = ds(3);
r__s  = ds(4);
m__r  = ds(5);
m__wr = ds(6);
r__r  = ds(7);
m__c  = ds(8);
m__wc = ds(9);
r__c  = ds(10);
m__p  = ds(11);
m__wp = ds(12);
r__p  = ds(13);
k__r  = ds(14);
k__s  = ds(15);
k__c  = ds(16);
k__cu = ds(18);
k__ru = ds(19);
k__su = ds(20);
k__m  = ds(21);
Omega__c = ds(22);
radius = [ r__s 0 0 r__r 0 0 r__c 0 0 r__p ]; % Array of all radius


MM = [m__c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 m__c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 m__wc 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 m__r 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 m__r 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 m__wr 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__s 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__s 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__ws 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__wp 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__wp 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__wp;];

%% ~~ Create Cell Array for K ~~~ %
for i = 1:(length(K_eps))
    k__p  = K_eps(i); % Random Value
    %% N = 3
    q = q(1:18);
    KK = [-m__c * Omega__c ^ 2 + k__c + 3 * k__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -k__p 0 0 k__p / 0.2e1 k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 0 k__p / 0.2e1 -k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 0; 0 -m__c * Omega__c ^ 2 + k__c + 3 * k__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -k__p 0 -k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 k__p / 0.2e1 0 k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 k__p / 0.2e1 0; 0 0 3 * k__p + k__cu 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -k__p 0 0 -k__p 0 0 -k__p 0; 0 0 0 k__m * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) ^ 2 - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__r * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__r sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - k__m * sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) - cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m + sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m - sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0 cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - k__m cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m; 0 0 0 sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - k__m * sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) - cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) ^ 2 + cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) ^ 2 * k__m + cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__r * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__m + k__r -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * cos(alpha) 0 0 0 cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m; 0 0 0 -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m + sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m - sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * cos(alpha) 0.3e1 * k__m + k__ru 0 0 0 sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -k__m sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -k__m sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -k__m; 0 0 0 0 0 0 k__m * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) ^ 2 - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__s * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__s -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) + cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + sin(alpha) * k__m cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - k__m -cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m; 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) + cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) ^ 2 + cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) ^ 2 * k__m + cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__s * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__m + k__s -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * cos(alpha) -cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m k__m * cos(alpha) cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m; 0 0 0 0 0 0 cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * cos(alpha) 0.3e1 * k__m + k__su -sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) k__m; -k__p 0 0 cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - k__m cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - k__m -cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m -0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__p 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 -k__p -k__p cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) 0 0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -k__m sin(alpha) * k__m k__m * cos(alpha) k__m -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0.2e1 * k__m 0 0 0 0 0 0; k__p / 0.2e1 -k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 0 -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0 -0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__p 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0; k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 k__p / 0.2e1 -k__p cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) 0 0 0 0 0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__p 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m -k__m -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m k__m 0 0 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0.2e1 * k__m 0 0 0; k__p / 0.2e1 k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 0 sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__p 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m; -k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 k__p / 0.2e1 -k__p -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__p 0; 0 0 0 -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m -k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m k__m 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0.2e1 * k__m;]; 
    Kcell{i} = KK; % Save each KK in Kcell array

    [frqs_KM] = eigenprob_KM (q_std,cell2mat(Kcell(i)),MM,ds(22));
    Fcell{i} = real(frqs_KM); 
end % for  

Fmat = cell2mat(Fcell);
for i = 1 : length(q_std)
    figure('Name','Natural Frequency with Uncertainty');
    NatFrqs = Fmat (i,:);
    s = scatter ( epsilon,NatFrqs', 20,'b','filled');
    s.LineWidth = 0.6;
    s.MarkerEdgeColor = 'b';
    s.MarkerFaceColor = [0 0.5 0.5];
    Fmat = cell2mat(Fcell);
    xlabel('\bf \epsilon \sim N(\mu,\sigma)','FontSize',14)
    ylabel('\bf Natural Frequency, \omega_{n}','FontSize',14)
    set(gca,'yaxislocation','right');
    title(sprintf('Designated Natural Frequency [Hz] = %f', ...
                   round(frqs_std(i),2)));
    ax = gca;
    ax.YAxisLocation = 'origin';  % setting y axis location to origin
    grid on
    hold on
end % for

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Functions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%

%% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Calculate Eigen-Problem for N Planets ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %
function [q,Kcell,MM,radius] = gear_eigen (randomvar,data)

%% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Define Simulation data ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ %

syms x__s     y__s    u__s ... 
     x__r     y__r    u__r ... 
     x__c     y__c    u__c ... 
     zeta__1  eta__1  u__1 ... 
     zeta__2  eta__2  u__2 ... 
     zeta__3  eta__3  u__3     

q = [x__s y__s u__s ...
     x__r y__r u__r ...
     x__c y__c u__c ...
     zeta__1 eta__1 u__1 ...
     zeta__2 eta__2 u__2 ...
     zeta__3 eta__3 u__3 ];

alpha = data(1);
m__s  = data(2);
m__ws = data(3);
r__s  = data(4);
m__r  = data(5);
m__wr = data(6);
r__r  = data(7);
m__c  = data(8);
m__wc = data(9);
r__c  = data(10);
m__p  = data(11);
m__wp = data(12);
r__p  = data(13);
k__r  = data(14);
k__s  = data(15);
k__c  = data(16);
k__p  = data(17);
k__cu = data(18);
k__ru = data(19);
k__su = data(20);
k__m  = data(21);
Omega__c = data(22);
radius = [ r__s 0 0 r__r 0 0 r__c 0 0 r__p ]; % Array of all radius
Kcell{length(randomvar)} = []; % Preallocate memory for cell array;

%% ~~ Create Cell Array for K ~~~ %
for i = 1:(randomvar)
    %% N = 3
    q = q(1:18);
    KK = [-m__c * Omega__c ^ 2 + k__c + 3 * k__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -k__p 0 0 k__p / 0.2e1 k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 0 k__p / 0.2e1 -k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 0; 0 -m__c * Omega__c ^ 2 + k__c + 3 * k__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -k__p 0 -k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 k__p / 0.2e1 0 k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 k__p / 0.2e1 0; 0 0 3 * k__p + k__cu 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -k__p 0 0 -k__p 0 0 -k__p 0; 0 0 0 k__m * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) ^ 2 - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__r * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__r sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - k__m * sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) - cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m + sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m - sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0 cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - k__m cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m; 0 0 0 sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - k__m * sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) - cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) ^ 2 + cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) ^ 2 * k__m + cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__r * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__m + k__r -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * cos(alpha) 0 0 0 cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m; 0 0 0 -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m + sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m - sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * cos(alpha) 0.3e1 * k__m + k__ru 0 0 0 sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -k__m sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -k__m sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -k__m; 0 0 0 0 0 0 k__m * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) ^ 2 - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__s * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__s -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) + cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + sin(alpha) * k__m cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - k__m -cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m; 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) + cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) ^ 2 + cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) ^ 2 * k__m + cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__s * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__m + k__s -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * cos(alpha) -cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m k__m * cos(alpha) cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m; 0 0 0 0 0 0 cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m - cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m + k__m * cos(alpha) 0.3e1 * k__m + k__su -sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) k__m; -k__p 0 0 cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - k__m cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - k__m -cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m -0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__p 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 -k__p -k__p cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -cos(alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) 0 0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 sin(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -k__m sin(alpha) * k__m k__m * cos(alpha) k__m -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0.2e1 * k__m 0 0 0 0 0 0; k__p / 0.2e1 -k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 0 -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0 -0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__p 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0; k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 k__p / 0.2e1 -k__p cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) 0 0 0 0 0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__p 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m -k__m -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m k__m 0 0 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0.2e1 * k__m 0 0 0; k__p / 0.2e1 k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 0 sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(alpha) * k__m -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * sin(alpha) * k__m -sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + 0.2e1 * k__m + k__p 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m; -k__p * sqrt(0.3e1) / 0.2e1 k__p / 0.2e1 -k__p -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) -cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * cos(alpha) * k__m -k__m * cos(alpha) 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.2e1 * cos(alpha) ^ 2 * k__m - (m__p * Omega__c ^ 2) + k__p 0; 0 0 0 -sin(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m cos(pi / 0.3e1 + alpha) * k__m -k__m cos(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m -sin(pi / 0.6e1 + alpha) * k__m k__m 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.2e1 * sin(alpha) * k__m 0 0.2e1 * k__m;];
    MM = [m__c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 m__c 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 m__wc 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 m__r 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 m__r 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 m__wr 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__s 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__s 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__ws 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__wp 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__wp 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__p 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 m__wp;];

    Kcell{i} = KK; % Save each KK in Kcell array

end % for
end % function

%% ~~~~~ Function for Calculating Natural Frequencies & Modes (MDoF) ~~~~ %
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ WITH 'K' AND 'M' MATRICES ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~%
function [natural_freq] = eigenprob_KM(q,K,M,w)

%% Compute Eigenvectors 'V' and Eigenvalues 'D'
[V,D] = eig(K,M);       
D     = diag(sqrtm(D)); 
frq   = (D);            

[frq_sorted,index] = sort(frq,'ascend'); % Sort frq values
mode_shape_sorted  = V(:,index); % Mode Shapes for each Natural Frequency

natural_freq  = frq_sorted/(2*pi);  % Natural Frequencies for each DoF

end % function
```

[image: Profiler Results]

Comment: Whenever you have a performance question always start with the profiler.  Also I don't think `Fcell` is preallocated like you think it is.  You have allocated a cell of empties.  You want a cell of arrays of `size(real(frqs_KM))`

Comment: thanks @Matt, I'll upload an image on the profiler. As for the cell arrays, what would be the complete syntax? I tried Fcell{size(real(frqs_std))} = []; but it gives me an error.

Comment: For the sake of love to Matlab, do not use 'i' as iterator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab

Comment: After `q = q(1:18);`, where does `q` get modified again?

Comment: @Yvon thanks for the iterator tip, I´ll start using other variables.
`q` does not get modified again in this example, but it does in my long script, I guess that for this example I could delete this line, thanks.

Comment: In general you should never mix numerics with symbolics.